# Referencing parent column in where inside include

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Basically I have three tables: Reviews, Categories and Tags. Tags are associated to Categories and Reviews. When I fetch the reviews, I can also fetch the categories associated to those reviews and also the tags associated to those categories. The thing is: those tags can be associated to multiple categories and those categories to multiple reviews, so let's say for example we have a Review R1 associated to category C1 and tags T1 and T2 associated to C1. If I have another Review R2 associated to category T3 and T4, when I fetch Review R1 it will also fetch category C1 along with tags T1, T2, T3 and T4.

My solution was to check if the reviewId is the same as, well, Review.id in the where clause inside the association table. So basically:

```
let options = {
            include: [
                {
                    model: Categories,
                    as: "categories",
                    attributes: ["id", "name"],
                    through: {
                        attributes: []
                    },
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: Tags,
                            as: "tags",
                            attributes: ["id", "name"],
                            through: {
                                attributes: [],
                                where: {
                                    reviewId: "HERE"
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
            order: [["updatedAt", "DESC"]]
        };
```

In that "where" statement inside Tags/through, I need to reference the parent model (Review) id, but if I call, for example, col("Reviews.id") sequelize says the attribute doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently posting the question here is the charm so I will be sharing the solution:

Instead of querying the select inside `Categories.Tags.ReviewTags`, I moved the where clause to the top and used the syntax described [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level) to use a top level where with nested objects. The resulting query builder object was:

```js
let options = {
  include: [
    {
      model: Categories,
      as: "categories",
      attributes: ["id", "name"],
      through: {
        attributes: []
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Tags,
          as: "tags",
          attributes: ["id", "name"],
          through: {
            attributes: []
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  where: {
    "$categories.tags.ReviewTags.reviewId$": { [Op.col]: "Reviews.id" }
  },
  order: [["updatedAt", "DESC"]]
};
```